# Running service as console app

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I am writing a Windows Service which exposes a WCF inteface.  This all works fine as a installed service.  I am incorporating changes so that I can also run it as a Console app for testing following the guide of serveral site like http://makit.net/post/running-a-windows-service-as-a-console-application.

When it runs as a service it is fine... when I run as a console it appears to run ok but when I test using the wcftestclient, I am able to add the service but calling the methods results in an error....

> Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid.
>
> A call to SSPI failed - Inner Exception:
> The system detected a possible attempt to compromise security

I have run this as administrator but no difference...

Here is my code

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using AgentCoreService;
using Interfaces;
using NLog;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;

namespace Service
{
public class AgentWindowsService : ServiceBase
{
    public ServiceHost serviceHost = null;

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();


    public static void Main()
    {
        var serviceToRun = new AgentWindowsService();
        if (Environment.UserInteractive)
        {
            serviceToRun.OnStart(null);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop the service");
            Console.Read();
            serviceToRun.OnStop();
        }
        
        Run(serviceToRun);
    }


    public AgentWindowsService()
    {
        // Name the Windows Service
        ServiceName = "AgentWindowsServiceSample";
    }

    // Start the Windows service.
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        if (serviceHost != null)
        {
            serviceHost.Close();
        }
        // Create a ServiceHost for the AgentService type and
        // provide the base address.
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/test");

        serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(AgentService), baseAddress);
        
        NetNamedPipeBinding pipebinding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();

        pipebinding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
        pipebinding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);

        var t = Type.GetType("Interfaces.IEchoString, Interfaces");
        serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(t, pipebinding, baseAddress);

        serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior());
        serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName, MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexNamedPipeBinding(), baseAddress + "/mex");


        // Open the ServiceHostBase to create listeners and start 
        // listening for messages.
        serviceHost.Open();

        logger.Info("Host open");
        logger.Info("OptimizerService is up and running with the following endpoints...");

        foreach (ServiceEndpoint se in serviceHost.Description.Endpoints)
        {
            logger.Info(se.Address.ToString()); ;
        }

    }
            
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (serviceHost != null)
        {
            serviceHost.Close();
            serviceHost = null;
        }
    }
}
// Provide the ProjectInstaller class which allows 
// the service to be installed by the Installutil.exe tool
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class ProjectInstaller : Installer
{
    private ServiceProcessInstaller process;
    private ServiceInstaller service;

    public ProjectInstaller()
    {
        process = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
        process.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
        service = new ServiceInstaller();
        service.ServiceName = "AgentWindowsServiceSample";
        Installers.Add(process);
        Installers.Add(service);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Were you running the service as a different user?

Comment: per the code, the service is running as ... process.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;

Comment: I have resolved this apparently NONissue... I was running on a AWS Workspace whic is effectively a Win2008 Server and there was some weird issue with the rights.  Once on a regular machine it was fine - no errors.